# Is there a faster way to convert a large list of dictionaries into a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries called **list_of_dict** in the following format:

```
[{'id': 123, 'date': '202001', 'variable_x': 3},
 {'id': 345, 'date': '202101', 'variable_x': 4}, ... ]
```

To transform it to a pandas DataFrame, I simply do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dict)
```

It works, but when a try to do it with a list of 20 million dictionaries, it takes about an hour to run.

Does Python have a faster way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple cases of fastest way to build a dataframe is a list of dictionaries.  Below timings show this.

Fundamentally reading 20M rows into memory will mean heavy use of virtual memory and swapping.  The primary optimisation I would expect to come from sharding and not needing all data in memory.

```
d = [{'id': 123, 'date': '202001', 'variable_x': 3},
 {'id': 345, 'date': '202101', 'variable_x': 4}]

c = d[0].keys()
r = 2*10**5
a = np.tile([list(l.values()) for l in d], (r,1))
d = np.tile(d, r)

%timeit pd.DataFrame(d)
%timeit pd.DataFrame(a, columns=c)
%timeit pd.DataFrame(a)
print(f"2D array size: {len(a):,}\ndict array size: {len(d):,}")
```

#### output

```
53.4 µs ± 238 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
90.6 ms ± 400 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
90.4 ms ± 1.45 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
2D array size: 400,000
dict array size: 400,000
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for dictionaries that have some different keys and some common ones?